# Error in running Java Code code ( Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4' )?

Tags: java, utf8mb4

Im trying to learn Java programming and how to link it with Database MySQL ...

Here's the Code :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws Exception 
    {

        System.out.println("Loading Driver ..");
        System.out.println("Loading Driver ...");
        System.out.println("Loading Driver ....");
        System.out.println("Loading Driver .....");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        System.out.println("Driver Loaded");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javabook", "root", "1234"); //Connect
        System.out.println("Database Connected");

        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(" SELECT * From acc_types");

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while (result.next())
        {
            System.out.println(result.getString(1)+ ""+result.getString(2));
        }





}
}
```

says :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2618)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.configureClientCharacterSet(ConnectionImpl.java:1880)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3499)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at main.main(main.java:22)
```

well i've been searching on Google and YouTube and no answer for such a problem ... and i've installed the programs well according to this tutorial step by step ... 
( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E30_-pQGQXs )

I really need help ....

Comment: What does your code that causes the error look like?

Comment: What's in `main.java` line 22?

Comment: You might want to post the related code

Answer (score 4):

The `utf8mb4` character set is specific to MySQL. It's explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html). The exception is because the JDBC driver doesn't recognize that charset. One solution is to convert your database encoding to `utf8`. Another is to use a different JDBC driver. ([MySQL Connector/J 5.1.13](http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/java@lists.mysql.com/14151747.html) and up supports `utf8mb4`.)

Comment: and im using connector/j 5.1.18

Comment: @user1294027 - Hrm. Are you perhaps using MySQL server 6? If so, you may need a newer version of Connector/J.

Comment: The lastest Connector/J does not support MySQL server 6

Comment: Thansk! It was issue of MySQL JDBC connector version. I upgraded from 5.1.9 to 5.1.47 and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Check your database and make sure the whole database + tables + fields have the same charset. 
This is a real table example, you can see the charset is set for the fields AND for the table. And of course the database was created with a charset too.

```
CREATE TABLE `politicas` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `Texto` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `Lng` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```